# Find how is random variable distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question:**
Let X be exponentially distributed with parameter λ.Let Y be integer valued random variable defined in terms of X by Y=m, if m≤ X <m+1, where m=0,1,2....

**My ideas:**
$p_y(m)$=$\int _m^{m+1} p_x(x)$ dx ,where $ p_x(x)$=λ$e^{-λx}$, doing this I got $p_y(x)=e^{-λy}(1-e^{-λ})$, is this right and if it is then how to proceed? 
**($p_x(x)$ represent p.d.f of X)**

Comment: Seems ok to me. A good check is to see if $\sum_y p_y(y) = 1$. You can check this yourself.

Comment: Can you help me to check (in continuous variable we can easily integrate over R but how to do it in this case)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series may help you with $\sum_y e^{-\lambda y}$.